# Calling Another Function to Clean An Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, coding-style

I have an array and want to clean it. I have a function that erases all the blank (or "") values from an argument/array. However, when I call that function using a second function, the array is not *cleaned*. Where am I going wrong?

This function works well. It cleans the array.

```
function cleanArray(myArray) {
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i]) {
      newArray.push(myArray[i]);
    }
  }
  myArray = newArray;
  Logger.log(myArray)
}
```

The below function calls on the above function, and it logs the *cleaned* array via the above function. However, when I try to log the already cleaned array, it just logs the original messy one.

```
function testCleanArray(){
var arr = [1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,]
  cleanArray(arr);
Logger.log(arr)  
}
```

**This is what I get when I run the Logs (Google Sheets script editor)**

```
[18-02-14 00:23:16:415 PST] [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[18-02-14 00:23:16:415 PST] [1.0, 2.0, null, 3.0, null, 3.0, null, null, null, null, null, 4.0, null, 4.0, null, 5.0, null, 6.0, null, null, null]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myArray = newArray;
```

This line changes the `myArray` reference inside the context of the function `cleanArray` to your newly created one.

It does not have the power to change the array that `arr` holds, which is defined in another function.

There are two paths you can take:

1. `return` the newly created array and assign it to a variable outside of `cleanArray` (my preferred approach)
2. Change `cleanArray` to mutate the array you pass to it, using, for example, `splice`, `pop` and `shift`.

For option 1, the fix would be:

```
function cleanArray(myArray) {
  var newArray = [];

  /* your for loop here */

  return newArray;
};


function testCleanArray(){
  var arr = [1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,]
  arr = cleanArray(arr);
}
```

Note that there's also an easier way to write your cleaning function using `Array.prototype.filter`. I've checked for `undefined` to make sure `0` values are also included.

```js
var myArray = [1, 2,, 3,, 3,,,,,, 4,, 4,, 5,, 6,,,,];
var arr = myArray.filter(x => x !== undefined);
console.log(arr);
```